# Graph labelling where vertices with a common neighbour get different labels

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring

**Is the following notion of graph labeling (let me call it special labeling) ever studied in the literature?**
A special labelling of a (simple undirected) graph $G$ is a function $f:V(G)\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(u)\neq f(v)$ whenever $u$ and $v$ have a common neighbour (i.e., $N(u)\cap N(v)\neq \emptyset$).

The closest I  could find in the literature is strong subcoloring introduced in [1]. A strong subcoloring of $G$ is a function $f:V(G)\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(u)\neq f(v)$ whenever $d(u,v)=2$ (i.e. distance between $u$ and $v$ in $G$ is two). The difference between the two notions is that special labelling does not allow two adjacent vertices to have the same label if they have a common neighbour. Both notions are the same for triangle-free graphs.

**Reference**
[1] *Shalu, M. A.; Vijayakumar, S.; Yamini, S. Devi; Sandhya, T. P.*, [**On the algorithmic aspects of strong subcoloring**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10878-018-0272-z), J. Comb. Optim. 35, No. 4, 1312-1329 (2018). [ZBL1400.90266](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1400.90266).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Special labelling' is not exactly $L(0,1)$-coloring, but is very close. In $L(0,1)$-coloring, neighboring vertices can get the same colour even if they have a common neighbor. Speciall labelling do not allow this. Special labelling is already studied in the literature under the name *injective coloring*.

> An injective colouring of a graph $G$ is a colouring $c$ of the vertices
> of $G$ that assigns different colours to any pair of vertices that have a
> common neighbour.

There are a number of papers on injective coloring. The main graph classes studied are planar graphs [1,2,3], chordal graphs [4], regular graphs [5], and sparse graphs [6]

### References

[1] *Bu, Yuehua; Qi, Chentao; Zhu, Junlei; Xu, Ting*, [**Injective coloring of planar graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2021.01.007),  [ZBL07300884](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07300884).

[2] *Lužar, Borut; Škrekovski, Riste; Tancer, Martin*, [**Injective colorings of planar graphs with few colors**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2008.04.005), Discrete Math. 309, No. 18, 5636-5649 (2009). [ZBL1209.05093](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1209.05093).

[3] *Bu, Yuehua; Wang, Chao; Yang, Sheng*, List injective coloring of planar graphs.,  [ZBL06986943](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06986943).

[4] *Hell, Pavol; Raspaud, André; Stacho, Juraj*, [**On injective colourings of chordal graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-78773-0_45), Laber, Eduardo Sany (ed.) et al., LATIN 2008 Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-540-78772-3/pbk). LNCS 4957, 520-530 (2008). [ZBL1136.68463](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1136.68463).

[5] *Hahn, Geňa; Kratochvíl, Jan; Širáň, Jozef; Sotteau, Dominique*, [**On the injective chromatic number of graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(01)00466-6), Discrete Math. 256, No. 1-2, 179-192 (2002). [ZBL1007.05046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1007.05046).

[6] *Cranston, Daniel W.; Kim, Seog-Jin; Yu, Gexin*, [**Injective colorings of sparse graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2010.07.003), Discrete Math. 310, No. 21, 2965-2973 (2010). [ZBL1209.05075](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1209.05075).

Answer (score 2):

$L(p,q)$ coloring is a function V $\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that the labels on vertices at distance 1 differ by at least $p$ and vertices at distance 2 differ by at least $q$. Special labelling looks like $L(0,1)$ coloring.

Comment: Are you aware of any paper that give non-trivial resuts on $L(0,1)$-coloring?